# How to Iterate through an array object inside another array object (JSON)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

The following is a list of users I receive from an API call that gets the list of users from AWS cognito. I want to be able to iterate through it to display the name and email of the user on a web page. I am trying `result[0].attributes[3]` to iterate to "given_name", **result** being the object. [image: I need the "email", "given_name" and "family_name"]

Comment: `result[0].Attributes.forEach(...)`

Comment: `attributes` ≠ `Attributes`

Comment: You iterate through a nested array the same way you iterate through any other array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` to determine if an object property can be found, and then return that object.

```
result[0].Attributes.filter(obj => obj.name === name);
```

Here's an example:

```js
let result = [{
  Attributes: [{
      name: "Mario"
    },
    {
      name: "Luigi"
    },
    {
      name: "Toad"
    },
    {
      name: "Peach"
    }
  ]
}]

function lookfor(name) {

  return result[0].Attributes.filter(obj => obj.name === name);
}

console.log(lookfor("Mario"));
console.log(lookfor("Peach"));
```

Comment: How does this relate to the data he shows, where it uses objects like `{Name: "given_name", Value: "Mario"}`?

Comment: @Barmar You can filter for any property or properties. The code from OP wasn't provided in code form and I didn't feel like referencing the image back and forth to create an example. It's the same principle.

Comment: You think someone who needs to ask this question in the first place will be able to extrapolate?

Comment: well I mean the someone is getting back a json object from an api, so I would say so. Can you console.log the full result?

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the pushback here, haha. Of course I expect OP to extrapolate. If it's over their head they can feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i in array){
   var attr = array[i].Attributes;
   for(var l in attr){
      // attr[l].Name returns name
      // attr[l].Value returns values
   }
}
```

Comment: [why is using `for-in` with arrays a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate an array using map

```
arrributes.map(function(arr) => {
  console.log(arr.Name, arr.Value)
})
```

Comment: You should use `forEach` instead of `map`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Object.keys(result).forEach(key => {
    let resultObject = result[key].map(array => {
      if (array.Name == "given_name") {
        console.log(array.value)
      } else if (array.Name == "email") {
        console.log(array.value);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: This won't work. There's no `given_name` or `email` properties, those are the values of the `Name` properties.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const response = [
    { Attributes: [
      {Name: 'given_name', Value: 'name 1'},
      {Name: 'family_name', Value: 'family 1'},
      {Name: 'email', Value: 'email1@gmail.com'}
      ]
    },
    { Attributes: [
      {Name: 'given_name', Value: 'name 2'},
      {Name: 'family_name', Value: 'family 2'},
      {Name: 'email', Value: 'email2@gmail.com'}
      ]
    },
  ];
  
  const users = response.map((ele) => {
      const { Attributes } = ele;
      return Attributes.reduce((agg, {Name, Value}) => {
        if (Name === 'given_name') {
          agg.name = Value;
        }
        if (Name === 'email') {
          agg.email = Value;
        }
        return agg;        
      }, {});      
 });
    
console.log(users);
```